# ReactiveMongo Scala DAO pattern

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have the following DAO, Service Object and Controller pattern in my Playframework project:

`CredentialsDAO.scala`:

```
def find(authType: AuthType.Value, authAccountId: String) =
    collection.find(
      Json.obj(Fields.AuthType → authType,
        Fields.AuthAccountId → authAccountId)).one[Credentials].recover(wrapLastError)
```

`CredentialsService.scala`:

```
def checkEmailPassword(email: String, password: String) = credentialsDAO.find(AuthType.EmailPassword, email).map(_.get) //Needs review
```

In my controller:

```
def auth = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    {

      val authRequest = request.body.validate[AuthRequest]
      authRequest.fold(
        errors => Future(BadRequest),
        auth => {
          //First verify username and password
          val authRequestResult = for {
            validCredential <- credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword(auth.email, auth.password)
            validPassword <- BCrypt.checkFuture(auth.password, validCredential.passwordHash)
            validAccount <- accountManager.getAccount(validCredential)
            session <- sessionManager.createSession(validAccount.id, validAccount.roles)

            touchedSession <- sessionManager.touchSession(session.id)

          } yield AuthResponse(session.id, session.token, validAccount.id, validAccount.roles)

          authRequestResult map {
            case res: AuthResponse => Ok(Json.toJson(res))
            case _ => NotFound

          }
        })
    }
  }
```

Question: Is this 'pattern' okay from a functional programming perspective? In particular, I'm bothered by this line in `CredentialsService.scala`:

```
def checkEmailPassword(email: String, password: String) = credentialsDAO.find(AuthType.EmailPassword, email).map(_.get) //Needs review
```

I'm new to Scala but I think there are better ways of dealing with `_.get` in the line above? Any suggestions/ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query returns None if the account id does not exist in the database, doesn't it? Isn't that a perfectly valid case? In any case, have you looked at authorization frameworks such as play-silhouette?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That is a valid case. Just wondering how that would affect my code or do I need to have a map/case to check for those conditions? I thought map will only 'map' values if they exist. For empty records, I just get an empty Future back? I'm busy testing it now, will find out shortly. Thanks for the play-silhouette suggestion. Will definitely look it up!

Comment: For the public functions of your API, it would be useful to indicate the explicit return type in the `def`s